# How to install miniconda on Ubuntu automatically

Tags: python, ubuntu

Download install file Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh from https://conda.io/miniconda.html, install it from command line. There are some questions need to be taken care of manually, like License, install path and adding binary into $PATH. My question is: is there any way to automatically install it by one command? Such as

```
bash Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    -license yes -install_path ~/miniconda \
    -to-bash-profile yes
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the answer below works really well. If it works for you too you should accept the answer to value the effort done by the author! If it for some reason doesn't work for you it's best to write a comment or edit your question!

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
```

`-b` is for for batch-mode, which includes accepting the license, and with `-p` you provide the installation path/prefix

[Seen here](http://stuarteberg.github.io/conda-docs/help/silent.html)